TargetAllocator distributing load to wrong collectors
TA configuration -
collector_selector:
matchlabels:
app.kubernetes.io/component: opentelemetry-collector
app.kubernetes.io/instance: namespace.app-metrics
app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: opentelemetry-operator
app.kubernetes.io/part-of: opentelemetry
matchexpressions: []
I only added the second label (app.kubernetes.io/instance: namespace.app-metrics), but it is picking up other labels from unknown sources. The other collectors are not designed to collect Prometheus metrics from the PodMonitor.
Ideally the collectors that Target Allocator(TA) finds should be the replica pods of the collector along which the TA is deployed. For example if a TA is deployed with "app-metrics" collector then it should only distribute the targets among the "app-metrics" pods.  Then the "app-metrics" collector's prometheusreceiver component communicates with TA to list down the targets. If a collector does not contain a prometheusreceiver configured to read the TA then nothing will happen.
Which is what is happening in my case. So, the metrics are not coming in the required collector.
I tried to add matchExpressions under the collector_selector but it didnt work. I also tried to add env variable.

Can you share the configuration for your target allocator and collector? the incorrectly formatted configuration is difficult to understand. I also may recommend opening an issue in the operator's repo
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/issues

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
